# ASTERISK. Добавление заголовка в CDR

Tags: asterisk

Aterisk 13. Настроенный диплан. Звонки работаю, CDR пишется.

Но необходимо добавить заголовок в CDR во время звонка.

Пример extensions.conf:

exten => _1XX,n,SIPAddHeader(Test-header: 123)
exten => _4XX,n,Set(CDR(Test column)=${SIP_HEADER(Test-header)})

Вывод консоли:

— Executing [6001@test:1] SIPAddHeader("SIP/100-00000000", "Test-header: 123") in new stack
— Executing [6001@test:2] Set("SIP/100-00000000", "CDR(Test-header)=") in new stack

Почему значение заголовка не передается? И возможно ли так делать вообще?
P.S. Колонка Test-header в БД есть.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, дело в том, что sipaddheader() добавляет заголовок к исходящему звонку, а SIP_HEADER() возвращает указанный заголовок из входящего INVITE'а.

То есть, если в продолжении этой ветки dialplan'а будет Dial(), то вы увидите добавленный вами заголовок на другой стороне звонка.